# Why is gradient descent used?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

It is clear to me how gradient descent works - we compute first-order derivatives in all directions, this gives a vector that points in the direction of the fastest growth of the function, and by following it in the reverse direction, we will approach the global minimum.

This is how it is mostly done in neural networks. And it even got its name - steepest gradient descent. But why? In case of convex function, we can just compute all partial derivatives, set them to 0, then find the root - and we get the critical point where the function should become minimum/maximum depending on the convexity or concavity. Why bother with gradient descent?

NB. Not sure if this question belongs in here though.

Comment: Finding the root may not be easy, or efficient, especially when there are many variables.

Comment: It would help if you provided actual functions being minimized. I doubt that they are convex, - neural networks would be unsatisfactory boring is this case. The main point of neural networs is approximating by something ridiculous enough (for multi-layered neural networks this is usually some frightening tower of weighted exponents) to be able to approximate any pattern, and this makes searching for exact solutions really hard.

Comment: How is that? If it is convex - isnt it easy? well, im not familiar with optimization very much...

Comment: Example I am reading exactly now - is about multilayer perceptron and backpropagation - E(w) = 1/2 sum_over_training_samples ||desired_output - output_of_newrons ||^2 - so in general all examples given deal with stochastic gradient descent but every 2nd slide it is reminded that this is approximation of steepest gradient descent...And I cannot get - why bother

Comment: @John It is convex on output_of_neurons, but not on the weights of the net, which are the actuall parameters to be optimized.

Comment: Another reason that hasn't yet been mentioned: even if finding the solutions to the minimum of a convex problem is analytically simple in closed form, it can still be computationally taxing (for instance, even inverting a matrix scales poorly with $n$, the number of data points).

Comment: I think I need to draw it somewhere... I think I midunderstood what I am minimizing...

Comment: @lisyarus, but if it is not convex, how gradient descent does not get stuck in local minimums? And neural networks have universal approximation property - so they should be able to approximate any function with any degree of accuracy so that means that gradient descent shouldnt get stuck anywhere...

Comment: @John Of course, it gets stuck in local minimums! It is one of the worst problems in optimization, and neural networks are not an exception. For the universal approximation property, it only says that there exists *some neural net* that does the approximation, without any restrictions on it's size. When one optimizes a net, it's size (and overall structure) persists.

Answer (score 3):

1. Even for convex functions, the equation $\nabla f(x) = 0$ is, in most cases of interest, does not have a closed form solution. So you cannot solve it, and you must use an iterative scheme (like Gradient Descent)
2. The same idea holds for Neural Networks, except that the function is, in most cases of interest, not convex, and Gradient Descent has a very low chance of producing the global minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, why we don't apply what we learned in calculus, just set the partial derivatives to zero and find the minimal.

I think the main difference is:

- Partial derivatives set to zero will actually find the minima for your training examples. But once you found your parameters for the data sets then you overfit your parameters and not sure your parameters will work on new data.
- Gradient descent allows us to minimize the error of the cost function but does not remove the error completely which is actually good since you want to leave some maneuver to your parameters to work on new data.

So I think in machine learning we are not trying to get the exact parameters to get the cost function to exactly zero but we want it to be close to zero. With the partial derivatives method set to zero we are actually solving the problem but only for the training data sets.